# Link com erro ao compartilhar no Facebook e Whatsapp - Site em Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, html-meta-tag

estou com um erro bastante chato na hora de compartilhar os posts do meu site em Wordpress. Assim que aperto para compartilhar no Facebook não carrega a descrição nem a imagem destaque e no depurador do facebook aparece dessa forma.

[image: Somente link, sem titulo, descrição e imagem destaque]

Link da postagem usada no depurador: https://amapa360.com/2019/03/em-santana-moradores-podem-fiscalizar-vereadores-pela-internet/

verifiquei o código html e as meta tags do facebook estão lá normalmente,

Tenho plugin Yoast SEO instalado porem não resolveu.

Answer (score -1):

Desative o plugin, embaixo da tag title adicione isso:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="...titulo do site..." />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="...Url do seu Site..." />
<meta property="og:description" content="...Breve Descrição do site..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="...Caminho absoluta da imagem..." />
```

substitua o valores do atributo content pela as informações do seu site (incluindo os pontos)