# Como aplicativos como WhatsApp e Facebook identificam os Logotipos dos sites?

Tags: link, html-meta-tag

Pessoal preciso mandar um link pelo Watshapp e gostaria que ele mostrasse o logotipo na mensagem

Fazendo um teste por exemplo com o site da locaweb: https://locaweb.com.br ele mostra um logotipo o titulo (tag title) da pagina e a descrição (tag description)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dei uma estudada nas metatags e adicionei todas que achei importante para isso no meu caso.

Será que esqueci de alguma coisa, pois ele mostra o titulo e descrição da pagina mas não o icone

Eu vou ficar devendo o link da minha aplicação porque ainda está em desenvolvimento e não posso divulgar por ordem da direção :-|

Mas as tags utilizadas são as abaixo:

```
<head>

    <title>{dinamico_title}</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="description" content="{dinamico_description}"/>
    <meta name="author" content="{dinamico_author}"/>
    <!-- FIQUEI NA DUVIDA SE COLOCO ESSA TAG meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" /-->
    <meta itemprop="name" content="{dinamico_name}">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="{dinamico_description}">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="{dinamico_image}">

    <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="{dinamico_title}" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="{dinamico_url}" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="{dinamico_description}" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="{dinamico_image}" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="{dinamico_secure_url}" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="{dinamico_site_name}" />
    <meta property="og:updated_time" content="{dinamico_update_time}" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="600" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="315" />

    <meta property="article:section" content="{dinamico_seccion}" />
    <meta property="article:published_time" content="{dinamico_published_time}" >
    <meta property="article:modified_time" content="{dinamico_modified_time}" />
    <meta property="product:price:currency" content="BRL">

    <meta name="twitter:card" content="product" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="{dinamico_title}" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="{dinamico_description}" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="{dinamico_image}" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="{dinamico_site}">
    <meta name="twitter:label1" content="{dinamico_label1}">
    <meta name="twitter:data2" content="{dinamico_data2}">
    <meta name="twitter:label2" content="{dinamico_label2}">
    <!--meta property="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="423021834"-->
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="{dinamico_name_iphone}">
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="{dinamico_url_iphone}">
    <meta property="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="{dinamico_id_googleplay}">
</head>
```

Vi um artigo aqui mesmo no stack [Link com erro ao compartilhar no Facebook e Whatsapp - Site em Wordpress](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/368655/link-com-erro-ao-compartilhar-no-facebook-e-whatsapp-site-em-wordpress) que é um pouco proximo do meu problema, mas eu não uso o wordpress e não consegui resolver mesmo aplicando a dica.

ps. Todas as TAGS vem de conteúdo dinamico como o codigo sugere, será que esse é o problema? São paginas PHP e não HTML puro

Comment: Eu acredito que seja da própria metatag `og:image`. Quanto tempo faz que seu site tá no ar? Pode ter a ver com indexação, não sei se isso é "instantâneo"

Comment: Então... se você pegar um link do peixe urbano ou mercadolivre por exemplo e colocar no zap ele ja mostra a imagem do produto então a questão de indexação me deixa na dúvida... será que pode ser o htaccess porque uso ele pra ter links "amigáveis"

Comment: Quando você compartilha no whatsapp aparece alguma coisa? Título, descrição, uma imagem placeholder...? Se sim, tenta acessar a imagem diretamente no navegador pelo link gerado para verificar se é um link válido

Comment: Sim... aparece o Titulo da Pagina e a Descrição, quanto a imagem eu abro o fonte dela, pego o link que esta em "og:image" e consigo acessar a imagem normalmente, mas ela não aparece no zap :-|

Comment: Qual o tamanho (KB) da imagem?

Comment: @Rafael Tavares, veja só, eu tenho um index.php que trata sessões e verifica se essa sessão não estiver ativa ele limita manda para a página inicial, acho que essa função está bloqueando o acesso a imagem quando não é pelo navegador, será que pode ser isso?

Comment: Esses icones são dinamicos conforme o acesso... mas a média de tamanho vira em torno de 10kb a 200kb, ou seja é pequeno

Comment: Acredito que o php não atrapalhe, talvez essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25100917/8839059) do SOen te ajude. Lá tem várias alternativas para tentar. Limpar o cache, a imagem ser menor do que 300 KB, `.jpg` ou `.png`... Dá uma olhada lá

Comment: Fiz um teste colocando um link de uma imagem externa e funciona, o problema está: ou no meu servidor no .htaccess ou no meu script php de entrada... vou ter que fazer uma varredura aqui.